# Sharepoint external access via vpn

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, login

We have a SharePoint 2007 server.

The sites can be accessed within the internal network. We want external users to access this site. I have configured VPN but when the address used to access internally is typed on the browser, it comes up with Username and Password prompt. On entering my credentials, it displays

> This page is not available

Please your input would be highly appreciated.

The URL used internally is in this format: `servername:port/***`

Comment: can you reach other internal resource with the same vpn? (to avoid some connection issue)

Comment: @NK Thanks for your prompt response. Yes I can access internal resources with the same vpn but only possible using FCDN.

Answer (score 0):

When prompted for credentials user should provide full Domain/Username and Password.

Assuming Windows PPTP VPN connection.

1. In the DNS section of the VPN connection settings, you should be able to define a DNS suffix to the connection.
2. Make this your local domain. (domain.local)
3. Register the connection and use the connections DNS suffix in DNS registration.
4. Save the settings and try the link again.

Comment: In the VPN connection, i have checked the tabs; "Register this connection's addresses in dns" and "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration"

Comment: In the VPN connection, i have checked the tabs; "Register this connection's addresses in dns" and "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration". The problem is still there

Comment: Amal, I would really appreciate your effort in resolving this. I am actually new in sharepoint and would welcome your kind and valuable response. I had in the past tried publishing sharepoint using isa 2004 in an attempt to achieve my aim but no success. so i decided to look in other methods i.e vpn.